# Scope Inside The Object Constructor Function

Tags: javascript

I am defining the consctructor function Foo as:

```
function Foo () {
    var a= 0;
    this.b = 1;
    this.f1= function () { return a; };
    this.f2= function () { return b; };
}
```

and I am creating the object as:

```
var bar= new Foo();
```

`return b` does not work, I have to use `return this.b` instead. But it work fine with the `a` variable.  Why?

Comment: The keyword this doesn't mean what you think it does in this context sir.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Because there is no variable named `b`

Answer (score 0):

Your function declares two types of constructs. `var a` is a normal variable that is scoped to the function and it is private within the function. It can be used any way the function needs to, so returning it is no problem at all. Most importantly, its value will not change from one instance of `Foo` to the next.

`b`, `f1` and `f2` aren't being declared as variables. They are being declared as "instance properties", meaning that their data will change from one instance of the object to another.  If you want to return an instance property value, you must use `this` to return the value associated with that particular instance.

After all, if you wrote:

```
var obj1 = new Foo();
obj1.b = 10;

var obj2 = new Foo();
obj1.b = 20;
```

How would you be able to keep the two `b` values separate from each other?  The answer is that you have two instances of a `Foo` object and the `obj1` and `obj2` variables each store a reference to their own instance.

When you write `obj1.b`, you need access to the `b` property that belongs to the `obj1` object instance. The `this` keyword does this for you.

Read on for more details:

The `this` object binding is volatile in JavaScript...that is, it doesn't always point to the same object and its binding can change from one line of code to the very next. How you invoke the code that contains the word `this` determines what object it will bind to.

Here's a checklist that you can follow to know what `this` will bind to...

If the code that contains `this` is invoked:

1. As a method or property of an object instance (through an instance variable):

   ```
   var o = new Object(); 

   // "this" will be bound to the "o" object instance
   // while "someProperty" and "someMethod" code executes
   o.someProperty = someValue;
   o.someMethod();
   ```
2. Via a `.call()`, `.apply()`, `.bind()` or `Array.prototype.fn` invocation:

   ```
   // "this" will be bound to the object suppled as the "thisObjectBinding"
   someFunction.call(thisObjectBinding, arg, arg);
   someFunction.apply(thisObjectBinding, [arg, arg]);
   var newFunc = someFunction.bind(thisObjectBinding, arg, arg);
   ```

   Additionally, several `Array.prototype` methods allow for a `thisObject` to be passed which will alter the binding for the duration of the method call:

   ```
   Array.prototype.every( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )
   Array.prototype.some( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )
   Array.prototype.forEach( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )
   Array.prototype.map( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )
   Array.prototype.filter( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )
   ```
3. If none of the other scenarios apply, Default binding occurs.

   3a. With `"use strict"` in effect: `this` is `undefined`

   3b. Without `"use strict"` in effect: `this` binds to the Global object

** NOTE: `this` binding can also be affected by using `eval()`, but as a general best practice, the use of `eval()` should be avoided.

Comment: The other source is also MY post. I am the other source.

Comment: Thanks. Although, I think you should upvote because it's the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

When your function

```
f1
```

is invoked, it asks it's environment/context "Excuse me, do you have any idea what [a] is please?". It responds with "Not here, but let me ask my own environment/context whether or not it knows what [a] is... ah hah, it says it knows what [a] is, and it's value is 0.".

When your function

```
f2
```

is invoked, it asks it asks the same question of [b] as f1 did for [z]... the difference is, the environment/context it is looking in for [b] does not include the instance of Foo to which [b] has been attached.

'this' in JavaScript is a tricky subject, and is covered in great detail in this [free online book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) which is part of the series "You don't know JS", by Kyle Simpson. A very good series.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't return because b is not declared.

```
function Foo () {
    var a = 0;
    this.b = 1;
    var b = this.b;
    this.f1= function () { return a; };
    this.f2= function () { return b; };
}
```

should work fine.

Or you can bind f2 method to "this" and return it:

```
function Foo () {
    var a= 0;
    this.b = 1;
    this.f1= function () { return a; };
    this.f2= (function () { return this.b; }).bind(this);
}
```

Comment: In the first code, note that the variable `b` won't reflect the value of `this.b`.

Comment: Off course it wont. In first example `b` will always be 1